# Firebase auth uidの扱いについて

Tags: firebase

AさんのuidをBさんが知った場合、Bさんは自分のrequest.auth.uidをねつ造して本来Aさんしかアクセスできないアイテムにアクセスできますか？

それともuidが他のユーザに見えても大丈夫ですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

バックエンドにWEBAPIなどが存在し、そこでFirebaseのUIDをキーに何か個人情報をHTTPで検索する場合などは当然脆弱性の余地がありますが、FirebaseのUIDをユーザーに知られても、FirebaseAPIから個人情報を抜かれることはありません。
ただ、基本的にBtoC系のサービスで、バックエンドで管理しているユーザーの一意キーを公開するのはおすすめしません。